# Any way to call Google Play store API in .net app to get additional subscripiton and transaction details

Tags: android, .net, google-api, google-developers-console

I have real time notification configured for app and I do get response like Subscription Id and Purchase token, based on this reponse I want to call additinal api to get more data like subscription, purchase and transactional details. I need to call thise api in .net. Please let me know if such api exists and how to call it in .net.
Based on google documentation I see purchases.subscriptionsv2.get api but I don't know how to configured so that I can call it in .net app.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with developing against Google services although I'm unfamiliar with Play and its APIs

Google (automatically) exposes **all** its services (APIs) through machine-generated client libraries called API Client Libraries.

Here's the list for [.NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis). There are several for "Google Play".

Here's the .NET documentation for [Android Developer API Client Library for .NET](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3.html)

Alternatively you can use [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) to browse all Google's services.

Here's the documentation for [Google Play Android Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/) and [`subscriptionsv2`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptionsv2) which includes the [`get`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptionsv2/get) method including its request|response bodies.